# Fatal Exception: java.lang.VerifyError when using Datastore with my own data class on some devices

Tags: android, protocol-buffers, kotlinx.serialization

So I noticed the following crashes at Firebase Crashlytics of my app which happens only for a couple of devices (so rarely) but still it happens:

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.VerifyError Verifier rejected class o3.c:
> java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] o3.c.E(java.nio.ByteBuffer,
> java.util.HashMap, java.security.cert.CertificateFactory) failed to
> verify: java.security.cert.X509Certificate[]
> o3.c.E(java.nio.ByteBuffer, java.util.HashMap,
> java.security.cert.CertificateFactory): [0x135] register v0 has type
> Reference: java.nio.ByteBuffer but expected Precise Reference: byte[]
> (declaration of 'o3.c' appears in
> /data/app/~~N1_TwW2swHQZzciPS8e0uw==/com.hidden_my_package.myapp-O87GcvydxMif4uP_FrnEXQ==/base.apk)
> kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__ShareKt.asStateFlow
> (FlowKt__Share.kt:38)
>
> com.hidden_my_package.datastore.di.DatastoreModule_ProvidePreferencesManagerFactory.providePreferencesManager
> (DatastoreModule_ProvidePreferencesManagerFactory.java:420)
> com.hidden_my_package.myapp.DaggerMyApplication_HiltComponents_SingletonC$SingletonCImpl$SwitchingProvider.get
> (DaggerBVRApplication_HiltComponents_SingletonC.java:420)

I can't reproduce the issue myself.

So based on the stack trace I have the following implementation of DataStore to save users' preferences:

```
class PreferencesManagerImpl(
    private val context: Context,
    private val dataStore: DataStore<Preferences>,
    lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner,
) : PreferencesManager {

    override val preferences: StateFlow<Preferences> = preferencesStateFlow.asStateFlow()
    
    ...
```

My custom preferences data class:

// the next free proto number = 119

```
@Serializable
data class Preferences(
    ....
    @ProtoNumber(62) val preferencesCamera: HashMap<String, PreferencesCamera>, // key - camera id
    @ProtoNumber(63) val useMiles: Boolean,
    ...
) {
```

// next free proto number 14

```
@Serializable
data class PreferencesCamera(
    @ProtoNumber(1) val cameraAperture: Float,
    @ProtoNumber(2) val cameraControlSceneMode: CameraSceneMode?,
    @ProtoNumber(3) val cameraControlSceneModeNight: CameraSceneMode?,
    @ProtoNumber(4) val cameraExposure: Int,
    @ProtoNumber(5) val cameraExposureNight: Int,
    ...
)
```

So yes, I use DataStore + Protobuf:

```
class PreferencesDatastoreSerializer @Inject constructor(
    @ApplicationContext private val context: Context
) : Serializer<Preferences> {
    override val defaultValue: Preferences
        get() = PreferencesDefaults.getDefaultPreferences(context)

    override suspend fun readFrom(input: InputStream): Preferences {
        return try {
            ProtoBuf.decodeFromByteArray<Preferences>(input.readBytes())
        } catch (e: Throwable) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            throw CorruptionException("The data could not be de-serialized", e)
        }
    }

    @Suppress("BlockingMethodInNonBlockingContext")
    override suspend fun writeTo(t: Preferences, output: OutputStream) {
        output.write(ProtoBuf.encodeToByteArray(t))
    }
}

object PreferencesDefaults {
    fun getDefaultPreferences(context: Context): Preferences {
        ...
        return Preferences(
            ...
            preferencesCamera = hashMapOf(),
        )
    }
    ...
```

The error mentions something about byte arrays and hashmap during this exception, I don't have byte arrays in my `Preference` data class, but I use `hashmap` there:

`@ProtoNumber(62) val preferencesCamera: HashMap<String, PreferencesCamera>`

By byte arrays it just means that something happened when it was trying to encode or decode data from protobuf file (*.pb), I guess...

But what could be the issue here as it doesn't happen for most users and only for some?

Comment: 1. Do you have logic in your application to migrate from SharedPreferences to Preferences DataStore? 2. Why are you using a ProtoBuf with Preferences DataStore? Or are you just using the Proto DataStore?

Comment: @tomerpacific 1. yes, but it's wrapped in try catch if something goes wrong and returns default Preferences data class, so there can't be any issue. 2. what do you mean exactly? What's wrong by using it? (ProtoBuf with Preferences DataStore)

Comment: Regarding #2, [there are two instances of the DataStore](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore#prefs-vs-proto), either Preference DataStore and Proto DataStore. As far as I am aware, if you go with the first option, there is no reason to use a ProtoBuff there as those are just key-value pairs of data. If you are storing more complex data, then you should use the Proto DataStore.

Comment: @tomerpacific I don't use first then because it does not provide type safety and it automatically generates class, no control of it. I am using an option when you create your own Kotlin Data Class instead of proto scheme file, and it's allowed, because  ProtoNumber annotations can work with data classes. Android docs are limited. We can use Kotlinx Serialization docs. Anyway I don't really see an issue here which method to use

Comment: @tomerpacific https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/formats.md#field-numbers